# Kivy: 'On_start' method not working when using ScreenManager

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I've been trying to teach myself how to use Kivy for a while now. I only had basic Python knowledge when I started, and I'm still quite ignorant on a lot of stuff, so I would appreciate if anyone can help me out with this issue.

It's a pretty simple code, it basically has a Label that works as a title, TextField that should work as a search bar, and a RecycleGridLayout on a Scrollview that should display Cards with text coming from MyList.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.app import MDApp

Window.size = (540, 960)

MyList = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]

KV = '''
<MyCards>:
    MDCard:
        md_bg_color: 1,1,1,0.3
        elevation: 10
        radius: 25
        
    MDLabel:
        text: root.name
        multiline: True
        halign: 'center'
        theme_text_color: 'Custom'
        text_color: 0,0,0,1
        font_size: 38


ScreenManager
    Main:

<Main>

    MDLabel:
        font_size: 42
        theme_text_color: 'Custom'
        text_color: 1,1,1,0.7
        text: "TITLE"
        halign: 'center'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.92}

    MDTextField:
        mode: "rectangle"
        hint_text: "Search"
        font_size: 26
        icon_right: "magnify"
        icon_right_color: 1,1,1,1
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.84}
        size_hint: 0.80, 0.07
        multiline: False
        line_color_focus: 1, 1, 1, 1
        on_text: root.set_list(self.text, True)
    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y: 0.75
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .4}
        opacity: 1
        RecycleView:
            id: rv
            viewclass: 'MyCards'
            key_size: 'height'
            do_scroll_y: True
            do_scroll_x: False
            scroll_wheel_distance: 50
            RecycleGridLayout:
                cols: 3
                spacing: sp(15)
                padding: sp(25)
                default_size: None, 150
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
'''


class MyCards(Screen):
    name = StringProperty()


class Main(Screen):

    def set_list(self, text="", search=False):

        def add_item(text_input):
            self.ids.rv.data.append({"name": text_input, "callback": lambda x: x, })

        self.ids.rv.data = []
        for text_input in MyList:
            if search:
                if text in text_input:
                    add_item(text_input)
            else:
                add_item(text_input)


class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        screen = MDScreen()
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        screen.add_widget(self.screen)
        return screen
    

MyApp().run()
```

When I run this code, [it doesn't show any card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/665Gm.png) at first, but as soon as I type something on the search bar and delete it, [it's all there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISe4k.png). I basically got the idea from this code provided by Kivy to see the icons available:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

from kivymd.icon_definitions import md_icons
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem


Builder.load_string(
    '''
#:import images_path kivymd.images_path


<CustomOneLineIconListItem>

    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: root.icon


<PreviousMDIcons>

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: dp(10)
        padding: dp(20)

        MDBoxLayout:
            adaptive_height: True

            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'magnify'

            MDTextField:
                id: search_field
                hint_text: 'Search icon'
                on_text: root.set_list_md_icons(self.text, True)

        RecycleView:
            id: rv
            key_viewclass: 'viewclass'
            key_size: 'height'

            RecycleBoxLayout:
                padding: dp(10)
                default_size: None, dp(48)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
'''
)


class CustomOneLineIconListItem(OneLineIconListItem):
    icon = StringProperty()


class PreviousMDIcons(Screen):

    def set_list_md_icons(self, text="", search=False):
        '''Builds a list of icons for the screen MDIcons.'''

        def add_icon_item(name_icon):
            self.ids.rv.data.append(
                {
                    "viewclass": "CustomOneLineIconListItem",
                    "icon": name_icon,
                    "text": name_icon,
                    "callback": lambda x: x,
                }
            )

        self.ids.rv.data = []
        for name_icon in md_icons.keys():
            if search:
                if text in name_icon:
                    add_icon_item(name_icon)
            else:
                add_icon_item(name_icon)


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = PreviousMDIcons()

    def build(self):
        return self.screen

    def on_start(self):
        self.screen.set_list_md_icons()


MainApp().run()
```

I tried using the 'On_start' method used here, but it gives me the following error when applying it to my code : AttributeError: 'ScreenManager' object has no attribute 'set_list'.

I would also like to add a FitImage to each Card, and make it so that the source of each card, is an image associated with the name taken from MyList. I actually got something similar to this to work, here's the code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView

Window.size = (540, 960)

MyList = ["Banana", "Chicken", "Eggs", "Milk", "Strawberries", "Tomato"]
MyImages = ["Banana.png", "Chicken.png", "Eggs.png", "Milk.png", "Strawberries.png", "Tomato.png"]


KV = '''
<MyCards>:
    MDCard:
        md_bg_color: 0,0,0,1
        elevation: 10
        radius: 25
        FitImage:
            source: root.picture
            size_hint_y: 1
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
            radius: 25,25,25,25
            opacity: 0.65
    MDLabel:
        text: root.name
        multiline: True
        halign: 'center'
        theme_text_color: 'Custom'
        text_color: 211/255,213/255,219/255,1
        font_name: 'BebasNeue-Regular.ttf'
        font_size: 30 if len(root.name) > 10 else 38


ScreenManager
    Main:

<Main>
    name: 'main'
    
    MDLabel:
        font_size: 42
        theme_text_color: 'Custom'
        text_color: 1,1,1,0.7
        text: "TITLE"
        font_name: 'BebasNeue-Regular.ttf'
        halign: 'center'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.92}

    MDTextField:
        mode: "rectangle"
        hint_text: "Search"
        font_size: 26
        icon_right: "magnify"
        icon_right_color: 1,1,1,1
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.84}
        size_hint: 0.80, 0.07
        multiline: False
        line_color_focus: 1, 1, 1, 1

    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y: 0.75
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .4}
        opacity: 1

        RV:
            id: rv
            viewclass: 'MyCards'
            data: self.rv_data_list
            do_scroll_y: True
            do_scroll_x: False
            scroll_wheel_distance: 50
            RecycleGridLayout:
                cols: 3
                spacing: sp(15)
                padding: sp(25)
                default_size: None, 150
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height



'''


class Main(Screen):
    pass


class MyCards(Screen):
    name = StringProperty()
    picture = StringProperty()


class RV(RecycleView):
    rv_data_list = ListProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rv_data_list = [{'picture': f'{x}', 'name': f'{y}'} for x, y in zip(MyImages, MyList)]

class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        screen = MDScreen()
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        screen.add_widget(self.screen)
        return screen

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

I used some food images as an example, and I get this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNXbj.png), this is sort of what I want, but with a functional search bar.

I think if we can get the 'On_start' method to work, I can figure out how to add the images and make it work, but if anyone has any ideas on how to do that as well, it's also greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for?  the code below should run.  I removed the special font from the kivy file. The magic of creating the top level screen manager in kivy was confusing to me so I moved that to the **init** and added the screens explicitly using the add_widget method.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView

Window.size = (540, 960)

MyList = ["Banana", "Chicken", "Eggs", "Milk", "Strawberries", "Tomato"]
MyImages = ["Banana.png", "Chicken.png", "Eggs.png", "Milk.png", "Strawberries.png", "Tomato.png"]

KV = '''
<MyCards>:
    MDCard:
        md_bg_color: 0,0,0,1
        elevation: 10
        radius: 25
        FitImage:
            source: root.picture
            size_hint_y: 1
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
            radius: 25,25,25,25
            opacity: 0.65
    MDLabel:
        text: root.name
        multiline: True
        halign: 'center'
        theme_text_color: 'Custom'
        text_color: 211/255,213/255,219/255,1
        font_size: 30 if len(root.name) > 10 else 38


# ScreenManager
#     Main:

<Main>
    name: 'main'

    MDLabel:
        font_size: 42
        theme_text_color: 'Custom'
        text_color: 1,1,1,0.7
        text: "TITLE"
        halign: 'center'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.92}

    MDTextField:
        mode: "rectangle"
        hint_text: "Search"
        font_size: 26
        icon_right: "magnify"
        icon_right_color: 1,1,1,1
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.84}
        size_hint: 0.80, 0.07
        multiline: False
        line_color_focus: 1, 1, 1, 1

    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y: 0.75
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .4}
        opacity: 1

        RV:
            id: rv
            viewclass: 'MyCards'
            data: self.rv_data_list
            do_scroll_y: True
            do_scroll_x: False
            scroll_wheel_distance: 50
            RecycleGridLayout:
                cols: 3
                spacing: sp(15)
                padding: sp(25)
                default_size: None, 150
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
'''

# depends on the <Main> in the kivy file
class Main(Screen):
    pass


class MyCards(Screen):
    name = StringProperty()
    picture = StringProperty()


class RV(RecycleView):
    rv_data_list = ListProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rv_data_list = [{'picture': f'{x}', 'name': f'{y}'} for x, y in zip(MyImages, MyList)]


class MyApp(MDApp):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Builder.load_string(KV)
        # the top level items have been removed from the kv file, build in Python directly
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        self._main = Main()
        self._my_cards = MyCards()

        print(type(self.screen_manager))

    def build(self) -> ScreenManager:
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(self._main)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(self._my_cards)
        return self.screen_manager

    def on_start(self):
        print(f"hello {self.screen_manager} is type {type(self.screen_manager)}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Any ideas on how to get a functional search bar with it?

Answer (score 0):

The key issue in the code is using a Screen as the base class for MyCards.  I have changed this to a BoxLayout in the code below.  The BoxLayout puts the Label under the MDCard.

Additionally, you are declaring the root widget in KV, and then instancing another Screen and ScreenManager in python.  I fixed this as well.  The builder.load_string() method returns the root widget.

I did not have access to your images, so you will need to restore your image list.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


Window.size = (540, 960)

MyList = ["Banana", "Chicken", "Eggs", "Milk", "Strawberries", "Tomato"] * 4
MyImages = ["Banana-Single.jpg"] * 4 * 6

KV = '''
<MyCards>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    MDCard:
        md_bg_color: 0,0,0,1
        elevation: 10
        radius: 25
        FitImage:
            source: root.picture
            size_hint_y: 1
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
            radius: 25,25,25,25
            opacity: 0.65
    MDLabel:
        text: root.name
        multiline: True
        halign: 'center'
        theme_text_color: 'Custom'
        text_color: 211/255,213/255,219/255,1
        # font_name: 'BebasNeue-Regular.ttf'
        font_size: 30 if len(root.name) > 10 else 38


ScreenManager:  # this is the root widget
    Main:

<Main>
    name: 'main'

    MDLabel:
        font_size: 42
        theme_text_color: 'Custom'
        text_color: 1,1,1,0.7
        text: "TITLE"
        # font_name: 'BebasNeue-Regular.ttf'
        halign: 'center'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.92}

    MDTextField:
        mode: "rectangle"
        hint_text: "Search"
        font_size: 26
        icon_right: "magnify"
        icon_right_color: 1,1,1,1
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.84}
        size_hint: 0.80, 0.07
        multiline: False
        line_color_focus: 1, 1, 1, 1

    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y: 0.75
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .4}
        opacity: 1

        RV:
            id: rv
            viewclass: 'MyCards'
            data: self.rv_data_list
            do_scroll_y: True
            do_scroll_x: False
            scroll_wheel_distance: 50
            RecycleGridLayout:
                cols: 3
                spacing: sp(15)
                padding: sp(25)
                default_size: None, 150
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
'''


class Main(Screen):
    pass


class MyCards(BoxLayout):
    name = StringProperty()
    picture = StringProperty()


class RV(RecycleView):
    rv_data_list = ListProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rv_data_list = [{'picture': f'{x}', 'name': f'{y}'} for x, y in zip(MyImages, MyList)]


class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        print('on_start')


MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Any ideas on how to get a functional search bar with it?

Comment: I've added an additional response that adds search capability. I've capitalized the search word - this is optional.  There are a number of different ways  to handle this depending on the search behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have added search capability.  Notice in the search box, when on_text fires, rv.search() is called.  A new method is added in RV.

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp

Window.size = (540, 960)

MyList = ["Banana", "Chicken", "Eggs", "Milk", "Strawberries", "Tomato"] * 4
MyImages = ["Banana-Single.jpg"] * 4 * 6

KV = '''
<MyCards>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    MDCard:
        md_bg_color: 0,0,0,1
        elevation: 10
        radius: 25
        FitImage:
            source: root.picture
            size_hint_y: 1
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
            radius: 25,25,25,25
            opacity: 0.65
    MDLabel:
        text: root.name
        multiline: True
        halign: 'center'
        theme_text_color: 'Custom'
        text_color: 211/255,213/255,219/255,1
        # font_name: 'BebasNeue-Regular.ttf'
        font_size: 30 if len(root.name) > 10 else 38


ScreenManager:  # this is the root widget
    Main:

<Main>
    name: 'main'

    MDLabel:
        font_size: 42
        theme_text_color: 'Custom'
        text_color: 1,1,1,0.7
        text: "TITLE"
        # font_name: 'BebasNeue-Regular.ttf'
        halign: 'center'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.92}

    MDTextField:
        mode: "rectangle"
        hint_text: "Search"
        font_size: 26
        icon_right: "magnify"
        icon_right_color: 1,1,1,1
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.84}
        size_hint: 0.80, 0.07
        multiline: False
        line_color_focus: 1, 1, 1, 1
        on_text: rv.search(self.text)

    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y: 0.75
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .4}
        opacity: 1

        RV:
            id: rv
            viewclass: 'MyCards'
            data: self.rv_data_list
            do_scroll_y: True
            do_scroll_x: False
            scroll_wheel_distance: 50
            RecycleGridLayout:
                cols: 3
                spacing: sp(15)
                padding: sp(25)
                default_size: None, 150
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
'''


class Main(Screen):
    pass


class MyCards(BoxLayout):
    name = StringProperty()
    picture = StringProperty()


class RV(RecycleView):
    rv_data_list = ListProperty()
    original = ListProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rv_data_list = [{'picture': f'{x}', 'name': f'{y}'} for x, y in zip(MyImages, MyList)]
        self.original = self.rv_data_list[::]  # keep a copy

    def search(self, text):
        text = text.capitalize()  # target words are all capitalized
        self.rv_data_list = []
        for d in self.original:
            if text in d['name']:  # if the search text is in the name... display if
                self.rv_data_list.append(d)


class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


MyApp().run()
```